# How to run prpl-server inside docker with PM2?

Tags: docker, pm2, polymer-3.x

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN npm install prpl-server
COPY build build/
COPY package.json .
COPY polymer.json .
COPY --chown=node:node . .
USER node
EXPOSE 8080
RUN ls -al -R
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js", "--web"]
```

and my ecosystem.comfig.js is

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'ozark',
    script: 'npm',
    args: 'start',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }],
};
```

and the start script inside package.json is

```
"start": "cd build && prpl-server --root . --config polymer.json --port 8080 && cd ../",
```

to build the container im doing

```
polymer build && docker build -t ozark .
```

to start the container i do

```
docker run --name ozark -p 80:8080 -d ozark
```

but when I browse to http://locallhost nothing loads and I dont understand why.
I have viewed the logs from inside the container and the prpl server is running on port 8080

docker ps gives me...

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
e7f633881e17        ozark               "pm2-runtime start e…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       80/tcp, 443/tcp, 43554/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp   ozark
```

Comment: I would suggest to use prpl-server-node as library and run actual nodejs application using pm2 to really utilize it's benefits. right now you are running basically a shell script using pm2 and I'm not sure how it will handle child processes. this might not be your issue here but I think it's worth considering